# cant seem to convert into a valid select statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Im trying to solve the following question:

**Display the week (e.g., 1-52), start and end date of that week, and the number of sensors’ temperature that were reported within that week, between Dec 1, 2011 and Jan 31, 2012, sorted on the week number in descending order.**

with the following select.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time,'WW') as Week, NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-7,'Monday'), NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-1, 'Sunday')
FROM REPORT R
WHERE R.Report_Time BETWEEN '01-DEC-2011' AND '31-JAN-2012'
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time, 'WW') DESC;
```

This is getting a few errors that wont let the query to execute correctly, such as not a group by expression.

It table REPORT is a list of reports, which have data, and report times.

**EDit:**

```
WE NEXT_DAY( NEXT_DAY( SENSOR_COUNT
-- --------- --------- ------------
03 16-JAN-12 22-JAN-12        1
02 09-JAN-12 15-JAN-12        1
02 09-JAN-12 15-JAN-12        1
02 09-JAN-12 15-JAN-12        1
```

It what is printed out.  It doesnt seem to group it only by the week, as you can see here, i believe that the ouput should look something closer to like:

```
WE NEXT_DAY( NEXT_DAY( SENSOR_COUNT
-- --------- --------- ------------
03 16-JAN-12 22-JAN-12        1
02 09-JAN-12 15-JAN-12        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't GROUP BY an alias. You must fully specify the expression you're grouping by:

I've also added a few things that might get further down the road:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time,'WW') as Week
     , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-7,'Monday')
     , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-1, 'Sunday')
     , COUNT(*) Sensor_count
FROM REPORT R
WHERE R.Report_Time BETWEEN '01-DEC-2011' AND '31-JAN-2012'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time,'WW'), NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-7,'Monday')
       , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-1, 'Sunday')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time, 'WW') DESC;
```

There are other problems with your query as well, as you will soon discover :-) You're probably going to want to use analytic functions here. You'll also wind up grouping by the other two columns as well.

EDIT

Based on your edit, I think this should get you closer:

```
SELECT week, first_day, last_day, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(R.Report_Time,'WW') as Week
             , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-7,'Monday') first_day
             , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-1, 'Sunday') last_day
         FROM REPORT R
        WHERE R.Report_Time BETWEEN '01-DEC-2011' AND '31-JAN-2012')
 GROUP BY week, first_day, last_day
 ORDER BY week DESC;
```

Comment: when running it, it says,  Error at line 2: Not a group by expression.

     , NEXT_DAY(R.Report_Time-7,'Monday')
                *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Im going to modify the question slightly, as test output seems to be off, due to grouping.

Answer (score 0):

In addition... The example of annual week table using ISO week. Change IW to WW if required. Use your dates for start/end dates and my format to get week_start/end dates w/out hardcoding of days as 'DY'. You do not have to use CONNECT BY if using table dates and BETWEEN operator. My example is not based on table. Remove unnecessary columns, add your count, group by ISO_wk# (or non iso), wk_starts, wk_ends...:

```
SELECT start_date
    , TRUNC(start_date, 'IW')                  wk_starts  
    , TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + 7 - 1/86400    wk_ends
    , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (start_date, 'IW'))   ISO_wk#
  FROM
  (
   SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')+((LEVEL-1)*7)-1 AS start_date
    FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
   ( -- Nbr of days / 7 = 52 weeks in 2013 --
    SELECT Round((TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 12), 'Y')-TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y'))/7) 
      FROM dual
   )
 )
/

START_DATE    WK_STARTS     WK_ENDS                ISO_WK#
-----------------------------------------------------------
12/31/2012    12/31/2012    1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM      1
1/7/2013      1/7/2013      1/13/2013 11:59:59 PM     2
1/14/2013     1/14/2013     1/20/2013 11:59:59 PM     3
...
...
12/23/2013    12/23/2013    12/29/2013 11:59:59 PM    52
```

Week number calendar to confirm wk dates and numbers: http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php